# Taylor series for $x\sin(x^2)$, looking for $a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I had to find the coefficient $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=x\sin(x^2)$,$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Hmm I thought since:

$\sin(x)= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

$x\sin(x^2)=x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x)^{2(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!}=x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x)^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(x)^{4n+3}$

But can I get this in term of only $x^n$? Or is this the solution?

I took some derivatives before and figured that indeed for $x_0=0$ as our center the first non-zero derivative is the 3rd.

So I dont see how we could express our function as a series with $x^n$ instead of $x^{4n+3}$

Could someone tell me if the solution for $a_n$ is indeed $\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$

Comment: There's a typo at the beginning of the computation: you should have $x^{2(2n+1)}$. Other than this, yes you have the solution: you only have exponents which are congruent to $3\bmod 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, for every $x \in \Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
x \sin(x^2) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{4n+3}
\end{align}
This can of course be written as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k x^k$ for specifically chosen coefficients $a_k$, but I doubt doing so explicitly is very illuminating. Anyway, here it is: define for each integer $k \geq 0$,
\begin{align}
a_k := \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $k \not\equiv 3 \mod 4$} \\\\
\dfrac{(-1)^{\frac{k-3}{4}}}{\left(\frac{k-3}{2} + 1 \right)!}&\text{if $k \equiv 3 \mod 4$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, $x \sin(x^2) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k x^k$. All I did was to do a case by case definition of what $a_k$ is, and in the second part, I simply set $k = 4n+3$, and solved for $n$, then plugged it into $\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$. So, again, while this is a complete expression for the various coefficients, I'm not sure how helpful you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x\sin(x^2)=x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x)^{2(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!}=x^{3}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=x^3 \sum\limits_{j=1 ,\text{odd}}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\frac{j-1}{2}}}{j!}x^{j}$$

Comment: This doesnt work out in my case I guess.. since $x^3$ isnt in the series I need to find $a_n$ for which my series equals the function. But this would ignore the $x^3$ you pulled out of the series... even if this is a solution is has the same trouble as mine, just in another wise. Or?

Comment: @CoffeeArabica yes, my expression is equivalent to yours. no, you cannot enter x ^ 3 in the summation by expressing it in terms of  x^n because n goes to infinity. you can represent x ^ 3 with a power series only if the limit is finite and equal to 3 es:
$x^3= \sum\limits_{n=0}^3 \binom{3}{n}(x-1)^n$

Answer (score -1):

By using the definition of Taylor Series, we write$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n,$$where $f(x)=x\sin(x^2).$ So$$x\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x\sin(x^2))^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$and if we let $x_0=0$, we get $$x\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x\sin(x^2))^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(x)^n.$$ By using the general Leibniz rule, we get $$(x\sin(x^2))^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{(n-k)}\sin^{(k)}(x^2),$$but if $n-k>1$, then $x^{(n-k)}=0,$ so$$(x\sin(x^2))^{(n)}=\binom{n}{n-1}\sin^{(n-1)}(x^2)+\binom{n}{n}x\sin^{(n)}(x^2)=n\sin^{(n-1)}(x^2)+x\sin^{(n)}(x^2).$$ If we plug this into series, we have$$x\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n\sin^{(n-1)}(x^2)|_{x=0}}{n!}x^n.$$